# Error executing SPARQL query in Eclipse using Jena and Yago 2

Tags: sparql, jena, querying

I'm trying to run a SPARQL query. I loaded the Jena Java API to my project in Eclipse. I'm totally new to SPARQL querying and programming with Jena.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.jena.iri.impl.Main;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sparqlTest();
}
static void sparqlTest(){
FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader());
Model model = FileManager.get().loadModel("yago2core_20120109.rdfs");
String queryString = "PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
                    "SELECT * WHERE {"+
                    "<http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Albert_Einstein> ?p <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Alfred_Kleiner>" +
                    "}";
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
try{
    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
    while(results.hasNext()){
        QuerySolution soln = results.nextSolution();
        Literal name = soln.getLiteral("p");
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
finally{
    qexec.close();
}


}
}
```

I get the following error when I run this program:

```
WARN riot :: {W137} Input is large. Switching off checking for illegal reuse of rdf:ID's.
```

Comment: Ignore the warning.  It's only a warning related to the number of bNodes in the file.  

You may be better loading the file once into TDB and using that database.

Comment: But I don't get any output at all. Later I get an exception OutOfMemory Exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using full Yago, it's quite large.  You can increase the heap size but better is to load into TDB and in your program, use that database.  That way, your program does not need to read the file every time it runs.

Comment: @AndyS, can you please tell me how to load Yago into TDB? I'm totally new to this stuff. So could you please explain? Thank you! :)

Comment: Command line: "tdbloader --loc DIRECTORY FILE1 FILE2 ..." (but call the file *.rdf).